# Why are there 2 windows opened here? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i was coding an application and I wanted to close a window and open another one via button. however:

```
from tkinter import *

x1 = Tk()
x2 = Tk()

def xd():
    x1.destroy()
    x2.mainloop()

boton = Button(x1, text="XD", command=xd)
boton.pack()

x1.mainloop()
```

This opens 2 windows, x1 and x2. I know already that if I use `x2 = Tk()` inside the function `xd()` , it will work how I wanted. But my question does remain the same. `x2 = Tk()` is supposed to only create a window name variable, and `mainloop` is supposed to create it, visually. So, why does this happen?

Comment: Why do you think the window shouldn't be created until you call `mainloop()`? If I just type `x1 = Tk()` the first window shows immediately. What `mainloop()` does is start the event loop so you can interact with the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single call to `mainloop` will make both windows visible. That is simply how tkinter is designed to work. Since you create two windows, you'll see two windows.

Comment: So, just writing ```mainloop``` works too? Why should I call ```x1.mainloop``` instead of ```mainloop```?

Comment: @FireFrekox: I don't think there's any reason to pick `x1.mainloop` over `mainloop`, unless you've explicitly configured tkinter to not support a default root window. I see no advantage in doing that for the vast majority of applications.